# Power BI dividing function shows negative value instead of positive

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem and probably it is very simple. There are sales values of 2 years for some markets in my data. I'm trying to calculate annual growths so I divide 2019 value of a market by 2018 value and then subtract -1. (Example: 2018 sales: $100, 2019 sales: $200.  Growth is `[(200/100)-1]= 1= %100`)  But some markets were 0 in 2018 and started to operate in 2019. Therefore, the growth must be `+%100`. But it gives `-%100`.

```
YTD19vs18 = (DIVIDE(SUM(YTDPerformans[YTD 2019]);SUM(YTDPerformans[YTD 2018])))-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sure it gives `-1` because thats the result of the calculation

```
(0 / 200) - 1 = -1
```

You can include a check for this case. Somthing like if the previous year is zero return always `1 = 100%`:

```
YTD19vs18 =  IIF(
                 YTDPerformans[YTD 2018] = 0; 
                 1;
                 DIVIDE(SUM(YTDPerformans[YTD 2019]);
                        SUM(YTDPerformans[YTD 2018]))
                        )-1
                 )
```